# Incorrect number of arguments in Expression.Call method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, lambda

I have a `ToFutureValue` method which converts a `IQueryable` to a `FutureValue` to be executed in the future. Here we are using `NHibernate` to convert `Linq to Sql` finally.

```
public static IFutureValue<TResult> ToFutureValue<TSource, TResult>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> query,
        Expression<Func<IQueryable<TSource>, TResult>> selector, params object[] arguments)
    {
        if (query is IFutureQuery<TSource>)
        {
            var futureQuery = query as IFutureQuery<TSource>;
            var method = ((MethodCallExpression)selector.Body).Method;

            // here we call method which has Expression.call statement
            var retval = futureQuery.ExecuteFutureValue<TResult>(method, arguments);

            return retval;
        }
        throw new FutureException(FutureException.WrongQueryType);
    }
```

Following is the method that has `Expression.Call()`

```
    public IFutureValue<TResult> ExecuteFutureValue<TResult>(MethodInfo method, params object[] arguments)
    {
        var expression = Expression.Call(null,
            method,
            arguments.Select(x =>
            {
                if (x is Expression)
                    return x as Expression;
                else if (x is string)
                {
                    // Problem is here......

                    Expression<Func<string>> arg = () => x.As<string>();
                    return arg;

                    // ................
                }
                else
                    return Expression.Constant(x);
            }).ToArray()
            );

        var provider = (FutureQueryProvider)Provider;

        var future = (Nh.IFutureValue<TResult>)provider.ExecuteFuture(expression);

        return new FutureValue<TResult>(future.Value);
    }
```

The expression method that I'm trying to call is the following, and it has been tested and works fine. Now, the `Expression.Call` must call this method and substitute the proper parameters. Here, it must take a expression and substitute a string from that expression. Thats what I'm trying to achieve in the above method.

```
IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string property)
```

However, I get the following error,

```
Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[Measurement.Model.Test.TestPieceDto] OrderByDescending[TestPieceDto](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Measurement.Model.Test.TestPieceDto], System.String)'
```

I think this is because the `Expression.Call` is not substituting the parameters correctly. Any ideas on how to substitute a string argument. Also note we a using a array of objects in `Expression.Call`, just in case there are multiple arguments. But, the method I'm trying to call has only one argument (this could be a problem, I'm not sure).